# Django sql order by

Tags: sql, database, django, django-queryset

I'm really struggling on this one.
I need to be able to sort my user by the number of positive vote received on their comment.

I have a table userprofile, a table comment and a table likeComment.
The table comment has a foreign key to its user creator and the table likeComment has a foreign key to the comment liked.
To get the number of positive vote a user received I do :

```
LikeComment.objects.filter(Q(type = 1), Q(comment__user=user)).count()
```

Now I want to be able to get all the users sorted by the ones that have the most positive votes. How do I do that ? I tried to use extra and JOIN but this didn't go anywhere.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to perform a filter on an annotation:

```
class User(models.Model):
     pass

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="comments")

class Like(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name="likes")
    type = models.IntegerField()

users = User \
    .objects \
    .all()
    .extra(select = {
        "positive_likes" : """
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_like
        JOIN app_comment on app_like.comment_id = app_comment.id
        WHERE app_comment.user_id = app_user.id AND app_like.type = 1 """})
    .order_by("positive_likes")
```

Comment: Thank Timmy, I was getting nuts and enable to make the query!
Now that I do that I get a DB error : syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 8:         SELECT COUNT(*) FROM axiom_alto_likecomment

Comment: I got it! it was because of annotate for some reason I can't have annotate and extra so I putted everything into extraa ^^ thanks again

Answer (score 1):

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    .........

    def like_count(self):
        LikeComment.objects.filter(comment__user=self.user, type=1).count()
```

views.py

```
def getRanking( anObject ):
    return anObject.like_count()

def myview(request):
    users = list(UserProfile.objects.filter())
    users.sort(key=getRanking, reverse=True)       
    return render(request,'page.html',{'users': users})
```

Comment: This solution is correct, but it will produce a high load if site gets a big amount of users or requests per minute

Comment: @Igor there are many ways to reduce that load if you want. He can use pagination which load 10 users per page. He can also get the top 10 or 20 users only, the others users they can search it. Problems have many solutions if you really want it.

Comment: I was doing this at the beginning but I think the extra is faster ^^ Thanks anyway because you solved another problem I had ^^

Answer (score 0):

[Timmy's suggestion to use a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15805964/68063) is probably the simplest way to solve this kind of problem, but subqueries almost never perform as well as joins, so if you have a lot of users you may find that you need better performance.

So, re-using Timmy's models:

```py
class User(models.Model):
     pass

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="comments")

class Like(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name="likes")
    type = models.IntegerField()
```

the query you want looks like this in SQL:

```sql
SELECT app_user.id, COUNT(app_like.id) AS total_likes
FROM app_user
LEFT OUTER JOIN app_comment
             ON app_user.id = app_comment.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN app_like
             ON app_comment.id = app_like.comment_id AND app_like.type = 1
GROUP BY app_user.id
ORDER BY total_likes DESCENDING
```

(If your actual `User` model has more fields than just `id`, then you'll need to include them all in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.)

Django's object-relational mapping system doesn't provide a way to express this query. (As far as I know—and I'd be very happy to be told otherwise!—it only supports aggregation across one join, not across two joins as here.) But when the ORM isn't quite up to the job, you can always run a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), like this:

```py
sql = '''
    SELECT app_user.id, COUNT(app_like.id) AS total_likes
    # etc (as above)
'''
for user in User.objects.raw(sql):
    print user.id, user.total_likes
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be achieved with Django's queryset:

```
User.objects.filter(comments__likes__type=1)\
    .annotate(lks=Count('comments__likes'))\
    .order_by('-lks')
```

The only problem here is that this query will miss users with 0 likes. Code from @gareth-rees, @timmy-omahony and @Catherine will include also 0-ranked users.